# Find all cells with escaped out formulas '=

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, escaping, indexof

I have a sheet with a lot of formulas that have been commented or escaped out (not sure which term, if either is accurate) with `'=`.  I'm now trying to locate and remove the `'` without any luck.

I can figure out the re-writing of the formula, it's just the locating of `'=` where I'm getting hung up.  I'm not really sure what the `... == 0)` portion of these `if` statements mean, so that's my first problem.  But I'm sure there is probably an issue with my `keyword` as well.

```javascript
function resetFormula(sheet, range) {
  formulas = range.getFormulas();

  for (var r = 0; r < formulas.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < formulas[r].length; c++) {
      var formula = formulas[r][c];
      var value = sheet.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).getValue();
      var value = value + "";
      // var keyword = "'="; // no results
      // var keyword = "'"; // finds all cells with '.  Not that BEGIN with '
      var keyword = "'\="; // no results

      if (formula.indexOf(keyword) == 0) {
        console.log("(formula.indexOf(keyword) == 0)");
        console.log("formula = " + formula);
        // sheet.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).setFormula(formula);
      } else {
        if (value.indexOf(keyword) == 0) {
          console.log("(value.indexOf(keyword) == 0)");
          console.log("value = " + value);
          // sheet.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).setValue(value);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- It is really difficult for me to debug your code without being able to see the file itself, but I don't think it is worth debugging it but rather create a new solution because your current approach does not follow the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), namely iteratively using `getRange`,`getValue` and `setValue` is going to cost you a lot of performance and therefore you will have to redesign your logic.

Your goal is to remove `'=` from the "formulas".

- Keep in mind that a formula like that is actually (like you said) commented out, meaning it is a simple string: `'=sum(B1)`. Therefore, using [getFormulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) is not going to work because the values you are interesting in are `strings` and not formulas. You need to use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) instead.

### Solution:

Assuming the following sheet with random data:

[image]

the following script will remove `'` from every cell that contains it:

```
function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const charToDel = "'=";
  const range = sh.getDataRange();
  const [values, formulas] = [range.getValues(),range.getFormulas()];

  const new_vals=formulas.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>c==''?values[i][j]:c.toString().
                               includes(charToDel)?c.replace(charToDel,''):c));
  range.setValues(new_vals);
}
```

and the result after you execute the script will be formulas in the relevant cells:

[image]

**Side note:**

I think it is very straighforward to change my code to adapt your logic. Instead of `sh` use `sheet` and delete `range` as it is passed by the function. Of course add the relevant parameters to the function.

**References:**

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: You are correct!  The `getFormulas()` function was just residual from the opposite function of disabling the formulas that I had just copied and attempted to reverse.  So I removed that.  And your solution DID work, however, it seemed to cause some REF! errors from copying formula results and pasting them as static data.  I'll mess with it more later and see if it's just something I need to change in my sheet. And I didn't post a link to my sheet because someone "reprimanded" me for that in the past claiming it was "poor practice" and that my code should be clear enough...

Comment: @TC76 Thanks for your feedback and thanks for trying it out. I updated my code. Please check again. It should be 100% correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to find the formulas which have `'` at the top of formula. It's like `'=`.
- You want to replcace `'=` with `=` by removing `'`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, as the other method, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using TextFinder. Sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .createTextFinder("\'\=")
    .matchFormulaText(true)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith("=");
}
```

- In this case, the value of `'=` in all formulas of "Sheet1" is replaced with `=`.
- If you want to usee this for all sheets in the Spreadsheet, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .createTextFinder("\'\=")
      .matchFormulaText(true)
      .useRegularExpression(true)
      .replaceAllWith("=");
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried @Tanaike's solution, but this is what I came up with earlier today.  I was searching for the `'` which wasn't necessary.

`var keyword = "=";`

```javascript
function resetFormula(sheet, rangeValues, keyword) {
  for (var r = 0; r < rangeValues.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < rangeValues[r].length; c++) {
      var value = sheet.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).getValue();
      var value = value + "";
      if (value.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
        sheet.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).setValue(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```